# c# UWP BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to write an app for my phone that connects to a BLE device.

The device is paired and I edited the appxmanifest to enable the bluetooth capabilities.

But when I run the app, the code below,

```
await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id);
```

results in an Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.ni.dll

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
var deviceList = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(GattDeviceService.GetDeviceSelectorFromUuid(GattServiceUuids.GenericAccess), null);
int count = deviceList.Count();
if (count > 0)
{
    var deviceInfo = deviceList.Where(x => x.Name == "XC-Tracer").FirstOrDefault();
    if (deviceInfo != null)
    {
        if (deviceInfo.IsEnabled)
        {
            var bleDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id);
            var deviceServices = bleDevice.GattServices;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working by using the GattDeviceService rather than using the BluetoothLEDevice class:

```
var deviceList = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(GattDeviceService.GetDeviceSelectorFromUuid(GattServiceUuids.GenericAccess), null);
int count = deviceList.Count();
if (count > 0)
{
    var deviceInfo = deviceList.Where(x => x.Name == "XC-Tracer").FirstOrDefault();
    if (deviceInfo != null)
    {
        if (deviceInfo.IsEnabled)
        {
            var bleDevice = await GattDeviceService.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id);
            var deviceServices = bleDevice.GattServices;
        }
    }
}
```